# How to run an ec2 instance on a port number less than 1024

Tags: https, server, port

I was trying to run my ubuntu ec2 instance on port 443 so that my website could be accessed on https://url without having to have a :(port number). However, when I try to run my server on port 443, it errors out, and says I need admin permissions. How do I make my server run on this port?